Custom richt text attribute with data in next-intl
I'm working on a database for a game and want to include localization and proper coloured texts, the problem I have is that the game uses <color=#76974>text</color> to set the colours and that doesn't seem to be suported out of the box in next-intl. Is there some workaround or intended feature I can use to get it working?
I tried using next-intls default translation values but that doesn't seem to work.
